# Funções async dentro de setInterval dando Syntax Error no HTML

Tags: javascript, async, syntax-error, setinterval

Bom dia/noite pessoal, estou com um problema bem chato, estou a criar um site para um projeto de biologia da escola, sobre celulas. Nesse site tenho preciso fazer um loop que executa uma ação, espera X segundos e executa outra ação, espera mais Y segundos e volta ao inicio do loop.
Achei alguns codigos usando funções async mas quando tento aplica-las o browser executa uma vez e me retorna um erro de **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier** na linha numero 1 do html(a cada 2s ele me joga o erro dnv).
JS:

```
    function first(){
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('first')
    }, 1000);
    }

    function second(){
    setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('second')
    }, 1000);

    }

    let run = async ()=>{
    await first();
    await second();
    }

    setInterval(run(), 1000);
```

Quando comento essa parte, o erro some. Não tenho muito conhecimento sobre async e await, mas já tentei de tudo para fazer isso e ate agora esse é método mais promissor. Espero que entendam o que eu quis dizer, muito obrigado e possivelmente boa noite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro está acontecendo porque você não está passando uma função para o `setInterval`.

`setInterval` recebe dois parâmetros; uma função, e o tempo em milissegundos para executar essa função. Agora veja o que você está fazendo aqui:

```
setInterval(run(), 1000);
```

`run` é uma função, mas ao utilizar `run()` você está invocando a função e passando o retorno dela como parâmetro para o `setInterval`. Porém `run()` não tem um retorno, é `undefined`, seu `setInterval` está sendo invocado como `setInterval(undefined, 1000)`, e isso é um erro.

Você poderia invocar seu `setInterval` como `setInterval(run, 1000)`, ou você poderia também declarar uma função anônima, assim como você fez no `setTimeout`:

```
setInterval(() => {
    run();
}, 1000);
```

Isso resolveria o erro declarado na pergunta. Existe mais um erro nesse código relacionado ao `await`

---

`await` serve para esperar a resolução de uma `Promise`. A sua função `first` e `second` não emitem nenhum tipo de sinal para sinalizar que elas terminaram de executar, o `await` não sabe o que ele deve esperar.

Você precisa embrulhar essas funções em uma promise. Ao invocar o `resolve` da promise, você estará emitindo esse sinal de que o `await` precisa para continuar rodando.

```
function first() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            console.log('first') 
            resolve()
        }, 1000)
    })
}

function second() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            console.log('second') 
            resolve()
        }, 1000)
    })
}
```

Agora sim, refatorando todo o código você teria:

```js
function first() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            console.log('first') 
            resolve()
        }, 1000)
    })
}

function second() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            console.log('second') 
            resolve()
        }, 1000)
    })
}

async function run() {
    // loop infinito
    while (true) {
        await first();
        await second();
    }
}

// ironicamente, você nem precisava de um setInterval
run();
```